# pyspark: insert into dataframe if key not present or row.timestamp is more recent

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-kudu

I have a Kudu database with a table in it. Every day, I launch a batch job which receives new data to ingest (an ETL pipeline).

I would like to insert the new data if:

- the key is not present
- if the key is present, update the row only if the timestamp column of the new row is more recent

Comment: Did you try anything in `PySpark`? If, yes what did you?

Comment: Hello @karma4917, I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure on how to proceed. In a more programmish environment, I would have sorted the dataset and with a scan I would have found the rows with same keys and execute the logic. this is not very much efficient (both in space and time) but It works. But I'm not sure on how to proceed with the spark logic in mind - and if there are other more efficient ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a left outer join of the new data with the existing table, the result of which you first have to save into a temporary table, and then move it to the original table, with [`SaveMode.Append`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes).

You might also be interested in using Spark Structured Streaming or Kafka instead of batch jobs. I even found an [example](https://github.com/curtishoward/spark-stream-kudu) on GitHub (didn't check how well it works, though, and whether it takes existing data into account).